# No packets show up in the POSTROUTING chain

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

My iptables setup:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "forward:"
$ sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "postrouting:"
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

When I start pinging (`ping 192.168.0.73`), the ICMP packet shows up in the *FORWARD* chain as expected:

```
[439971.459934] forward:IN=cb-localnet OUT=cb-localnet PHYSIN=cg.co92 PHYSOUT=cg-localnet MAC=ce:33:5a:f8:20:2c:36:fd:f6:30:12:b5:08:00 SRC=192.168.50.42 DST=192.168.0.73 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=36065 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=29 SEQ=1 
[439971.459972] forward:IN=cc-localnet OUT=wlp2s0 MAC=ce:33:5a:f8:20:2c:36:fd:f6:30:12:b5:08:00 SRC=192.168.50.42 DST=192.168.0.73 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=36065 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=29 SEQ=1
```

It shows up twice because there is a bridge (named *cb-localnet*) involved.

Ditto for forwarded TCP traffic (`telnet 192.168.0.73 2222`), it shows up in the *FORWARD* chain:

```
[440712.683183] forward:IN=cb-localnet OUT=cb-localnet PHYSIN=cg.co92 PHYSOUT=cg-localnet MAC=ce:33:5a:f8:20:2c:36:fd:f6:30:12:b5:08:00 SRC=192.168.50.42 DST=192.168.0.73 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=20623 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59052 DPT=2222 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[440712.683222] forward:IN=cc-localnet OUT=wlp2s0 MAC=ce:33:5a:f8:20:2c:36:fd:f6:30:12:b5:08:00 SRC=192.168.50.42 DST=192.168.0.73 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=20623 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59052 DPT=2222 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

However, these forwarded packets don't show up in the *POSTROUTING* chain. **How can I fix that?** I want to fix it because I want to enable masquerading:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(This didn't work, the ping didn't get an reply.)

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Linux 5.4.0 does some optimization which prevents running some packets through *POSTROUTING*.

The solution to make logging work was adding a dummy rule to the *POSTROUTING* chain. Any of these work (in addition to `-j LOG`):

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o . -j MASQUERADE
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o . -j NETMAP --to 0
```

Even after this, not all packets get logged. For example, only the first (with *SEQ=0*) ICMP echo request and only the first TCP packet (with SYN) gets logged.

---

I was able to solve the actual NAT problem (i.e. that `-j MASQUERADE` doesn't work) by running:

```
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Comment: Setting `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` to 0 means [the packets do not go through iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/162366/iptables-bridge-and-forward-chain#answer-455631). So in other words, any FORWARD or MASQUERADE rule would be totally ignored.

Comment: It does not mean it does not go through iptables, it means it does not go through iptables when traveling from one bridge to another without being routed.  If it makes it to another bridge interface that routes it to another interface it will call iptables at that point.